# Pandas: calculating mean value for rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like:

```
                     C   E    H
     window
(AAA, AAA, AAA)      26  4  111
(AAA, AAA, AAC)       3  1    1
```

And a dictionary called `p_dict`. 
Each value in `df['window']` has three sets of letters, and each three set is a key in my `p_dict`. What i've done so far to achieve what I want is:

```
dim_list = []
for word in df['window']:
   a = p_dict[word[2:5]] # len of 100
   b = p_dict[word[9:12]] # len of 100
   c = p_dict[word[16:19]] # len of 100

   flav = [statistics.mean(k) for k in zip(a, b, c)]
   dim_list.append(flav)

df['dimensions'] = dim_list
```

But this process is very long for a df with 1mil rows. Is there any other way of doing this?

*Edit*
`p_dict` looks like 
`{'AAA':[0.2, 12, 301..], 'AAC':[31, 0.91, 8..]}`
where each value is an embedding in a 100 dimensional space.

What I want to get:
For each triplet in window, obtain the 100 dimensions from the dictionary and work out the average to get one average list of dimensions.
so for window `(AAA, AAA, AAC)`:

```
AAA -> p_dict['AAA'] -> [100 dimensions] # list 1
AAA -> p_dict['AAA'] -> [100 dimensions] # list 2
AAC -> p_dict['AAC'] -> [100 dimensions] # list 3
output = average of list 1 + 2 + 3
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused could you add an example of your dict? and what you wanna achive?

Comment: use `df.mean(axis=0)`

Comment: @steven I have added an example of the dictionary. I want to be able to work out the average of three vectors given the key is a triplet in df['window']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split the words in `windows` so that you have a `n x 3` dataframe. Then use `replace` and `mean(axis=1)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'window': ['(AAA, AAA, AAA)', '(AAA, AAA, AAC)'],
 'C': [26, 3],
 'E': [4, 1],
 'H': [111, 1]})

p_dict = {'AAA':1, 'AAC':2}

(df['window'].str[1:-1]
             .str.split(',\s*', expand=True)
             .replace(p_dict).mean(axis=1)
)
```

gives:

```
0    1.000000
1    1.333333
dtype: float64
```

In the case your `p_dict` is dict of lists, we only need to tweak a little:

```
p_dict = {'AAA':[0.2, 12, 301.], 'AAC':[31, 0.91, 8.]} 
p_df = pd.DataFrame(p_dict).T

new_df = (df['window'].str[1:-1]
             .str.split(',\s*', expand=True)
             .stack()
         )

pd.DataFrame(p_df.loc[new_df].values, 
             index=new_df.index).mean(level=0)
```

gives you:

```
           0          1           2
0   0.200000  12.000000  301.000000
1  10.466667   8.303333  203.333333
```

**Note** it only works if the lists in the dict are of the same size for now.

Comment: I like this but I dont think it will work if my values in the dictionary are a list. I want the output to be one list that is an average of three lists given the key.

Comment: Ah I seem to be getting this error: ```KeyError: 'None of [0  0    AAA\n   1    AAA\n   2    AAA\n1  0    AAA\n   1    AAA\n   2    AAC\ndtype: object] are in the [index]'```

Comment: Make sure you transpose `p_df` with the `T` after `pd.DataFrame`